# Calculate Interpolation coefficients for random points in scipy/python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Given a set of points with coordinates x, y, z and a function value f(x, y, z), I want to interpolate a new function value for a new coordinate.
Since this computation will be done on a gpu I want to precompute the interpolation coefficients with python.

So basically I need some kind of function which returns interpolation coefficients for a given set of points and function values.
Usually the interpolation uses just a couple of points (8 - 16)

I thought about using the griddata function from python, see:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata
or using an RBF Function. 
But im not sure how to get the interpolation scheme/coefficients
from these python functions. Also im not sure which interpolation scheme is best suited for this kind of problem.

Thank you for any suggestions